# Separate your tf tree to have crucial frames update at a high frequency

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, tf-tree, tf

I'm calculating inverse kinematics for a low latency system but my robot's tf tree is so large, the time it takes to update the whole tf tree affects the calculation time significantly for my application. Is there an implementation or feature to have just the frames I need to calculate IK to have a priority in the tree and update and a much higher rate? Would this idea even be effective?

Maybe creating a mini tf tree with just the frames I need to calculate IK, then feed that info into the original tf tree? Maybe do something with namespacing to have another tf topic? For example: `/mini/tf`.

Do I just need a stronger computer?

I'm looking for some inspiration or for anyone to point me in a direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tf2_server](https://index.ros.org/p/tf2_server/github-peci1-tf2_server/#noetic) is the solution for ROS 1. It has several modes of working. In one, you can set a list of transforms of interest (or whole subtrees) and it will start publishing just the subtree on a namespaced tf topic. On the client side, you just remap `/tf` to the namespaced topic and you're done.

Search for the "streams" functionality in the readme.

Don't hesitate to ask for details if you face any problems using the package.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know this existed. I'll look into the [ROS 2 version of tf2_buffer_server](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/humble/tf2_ros/src/buffer_server.cpp).

Comment: Do you know how I would translate what I currently have to this server buffer format? I publish `joint_states` through the `joint_states_publisher` and that is reflected in the `tf` topic through the `robot_state_publisher`. For the server buffer, it looks like I need to send a geometry transform.

Comment: Resources: [tf2_ros](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/tf2_ros/namespacetf2__ros.html), [tf2_ros::BufferClient](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/tf2_ros/classtf2__ros_1_1BufferClient.html), [tf2_ros::BufferServer](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/tf2_ros/classtf2__ros_1_1BufferServer.html)

Comment: Be aware that tf2_buffer_server is not the same thing as our package tf2_server. I don't think tf2_buffer_server would help you much in your low-latency application for two reasons: 1) service-response is slower than topic subscription, 2) the node running the server would anyways process the whole tree, which you say is too slow. If you're using ROS 2, tf2_server has not been ported yet. But contributions towards a ROS 2 version are welcome :)

Comment: Or you can create a customized one-off filter of the /tf topic, which would be a simplified version of our tf2_server. Basically, you subscribe /tf and publish /mini/tf where you only let your transforms of interest. And then your IK node subscribes to /mini/tf instead of /tf. Be aware you might also need to handle /tf_static properly. What you could maybe try to get the best efficiency would be content-filtered subscriptions and set up the content filter to only send you the tfs you need. But that's totally untested and I'm not sure if it would result in lower latency.